# How to tell in which row a certain matrix column is mentioned/introduced?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The TikZ & PGF manual for version 3.0.1a states in section 20 (Matrices and Alignment), subsection 20.3.2 (Setting and Adjusting Column and Row Spacing) in the end of p. 307:

> The `between origins` option can only be used for columns mentioned in the first row, that is, you cannot specify this option for columns introduced only in later rows.

I'm perplexed by the expressions 'columns mentioned in the first row' and 'columns introduced only in later rows'. How can I tell which columns are mentioned in a certain row? How can I tell in which row a certain column is introduced?

Isn't it an inherent structural property of every table/matrix that all columns are featured in every row, and vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `TikZ matrix` is just a collection of nodes organized in rows. Elements in each row are separated by `&` and the end of every row is declared with `\\`. But there is no need for all rows having the same number of columns. Then it's possible to declare new columns in each new row. Not all columns have to be declared in first row.

As an example:

The first row only declares two nodes, while all other rows have three, and the distance between nodes from first and second column applies `between origins` while distance between second and third columns not.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [draw,column sep={1cm,between origins},nodes=draw]
{
\node(a1) {123}; & \node(b1) {1};\\ 
\node(a2) {12}; & \node(b2) {12}; & \node(c2) {1}; \\
\node(a3) {1}; & \node(b3) {123}; & \node(c3) {1}; \\
};
\draw [<->,red,thick] (a1.center) -- ++(0:1cm) node [above,midway] {1cm};
\draw [<->,red,thick] (a2.center) -- ++(0:1cm) node [above,midway] {1cm};
\draw [<->,red,thick] (a3.center) -- ++(0:1cm) node [above,midway] {1cm};
\draw [<->,red,thick] (b2.center) -- ++(0:1cm) node [above,midway] {1cm};
\draw [<->,red,thick] (b3.center) -- ++(0:1cm) node [above,midway] {1cm};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I understand better now. Why is there space between the 2nd and 3rd columns? Should they be touching each other?

Comment: @EvanAad `column sep=1cm` applies to all columns, only `between origins` is applied to columns defined on first row.

Comment: I see. So why isn't the space between the right edge of the 2nd column and the left edge of the 3rd column 1cm?

Comment: A beautiful answer! (and I don't even use `tikz`)

Comment: @EvanAad I don't know but I guess that the second column uses `center` anchor due to `between origins` and the third one still uses `west` anchor due to default `between borders` option.

Comment: Sounds to me like a bug, considering the quote I cited in my original post! One last question, please: if a column is preceded by an ampersand (&), it is considered to be 'mentioned' in this row for the purposes of `between origins`, even if it is completely empty, right?

Comment: @EvanAad It is measuring from the empty node in the top right corner. It's not a bug, place an empty node there to see it

Comment: @percusse: I don't see how this is not a bug. According to p. 307 there are exactly two keywords that can appear in the list given as value to the `/tikz/column sep` option: `between origins` and `between borders`. These keywords are mutually exclusive; whichever appears last "wins". The `between borders` keyword acts as the initial value in the sense that if neither `between origins` nor `between borders` is specified, or if the `/tikz/column sep` option is missing, it's as if the `between borders` value was given. But in Ignasi's picture neither setting holds between the 2nd and 3rd columns.

Comment: @EvanAad You don't have anything to measure in the first row so it places the measurement at zero in the 3rd column. The border and the center is the same point if you don't have anything

Comment: @percusse: Are you saying that the center of the 3rd, missing cell on the 1st row is located on the line that runs through the left edges of the other two cells in the 3rd column?

Comment: @EvanAad Yes just place another `&` in the top row and it will correct itself.

Comment: @percusse: But once you place another & in the top row the situation is completely different, because then the 3rd column is mentioned in the first row, and therefore the caveat mentioned in the quote I cited in my original post doesn't apply, and `between origins` takes effect.

Comment: @percusse: Besides, if in fact the center of the missing cell in the first row lied on the line that runs along the left edges of the two other cells in the 3rd column, then this would violate the vertical alignment principle of matrix columns, which states (see last paragraph on p. 306) that the (0,0) point of each cell of the same column must lie along a common line.

Comment: @EvanAad You are overinterpreting the names of the keys. If you don't have anything measured in the first row then you don't get a correction for the origin on the third column. There is nothing else left to say it. If you do have a third column then things get aligned based on that. There is no magical tuning. It's just a shift amount computed from the consecutive columns. If you don't have stuff in it you get a fixed shift which is happening here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62147/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-percusse).