# Inconsistent distance between matrix columns when the first row is missing cells and the `between origins` matrix option is specified

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you please explain the column positioning in the following matrix?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[nodes=draw,column sep={1cm,between origins}]
  {
    \node {1}; \\
    \node {4}; & \node {5}; & \node {6}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A 3 column matrix]

Comment: does the @ignasi answer on your previous similar (equal) question not sufficient?

Comment: @Zarko: Not at all.

Comment: why do you say "not at all"?, that answer and egreg's answer here show why your input here is invalid as you can only use this spacing between columns used in the first row and here you only have one column in the first row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If my input here is invalid, why does the manuscript compile with no errors and warnings and produces an output?

Comment: tex is a macro language catching all bad input is tricky, but if a package documents some constraint on the input and you make input that does not meet that constraint, whether or not the system flags an error, any output is just random accidental code and nothing it produces is either right or wrong, it's just wrong input.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Except the package document lists no such constraint.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Unless you interpret the quote I cited [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380483/21685) as a constraint on the input. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes exactly I was just going by the text that you quoted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I see. So what you're saying is: if I specify `between origins` in the matrix option list and my first row doesn't have at least as many &'s as any other row, then the input is invalid and the resulting picture is undefined. Correct?

Comment: that's what the  text that you quoted means yes (I am no expert on this I don't think I even knew of the option other than this question)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Well, this is the best answer yet. If you post it, I'll accept it.

Comment: no it's what egreg says in his answer, much as I'd love to avoid egreg getting a tick there are rules to the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the cells, even if empty.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[nodes=draw,column sep={1cm,between origins}]
  {
    \node {1}; \\
    \node {4}; & \node {5}; & \node {6}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[nodes=draw,column sep={1cm,between origins}]
  {
    \node {1}; & & \\
    \node {4}; & \node {5}; & \node {6}; \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Top is your input, bottom the fixed one.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, but for a different question.

Comment: @EvanAad Well, the explanation is that you aren't specifying the columns in the first row. That's all.

Comment: OK. I understand now. I didn't understand that the input itself is invalid and therefore the output is undefined and so there's really no sense in looking for an explanation for why it looks like it does.